# Caching Google Maps

Tags: caching, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am working on Google map application using **Google Maps JavaScript API V2**.

In my application there is Google map and overlays, my application refresh after every 5 second to fetch new records from database to update overlays. When my application refresh its reload the Google map.

I want to cache the Google Maps so that instead of reloading it retrieve map from cache until I update the location of map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you want to store the map tiles to a harddisk. To make your directory structure more efficent you want to reduce the map tiles to an one-dimensional problem using a space-filling-curve. Then you can store the map tiles for each node and edge in separate folders.

Comment: can you give more detail or any tutorial link?

Comment: It's just an idea, I would like to have a project likes this, too: http://blog.notdot.net/2009/11/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Spatial-indexing-with-Quadtrees-and-Hilbert-Curves